# React If / else for picture src

Tags: reactjs, image, function, if-statement

I want the image src for  to change based on the value of the "p" element. I have imported all of my images like this:

`import food from '../../images/food.png'`

**I've tried to use if/else statements and wrapping them in a function, then mounting them with componentDidMount when the page loads up, but that doesn't work for me. Then I tried :**

```
    images = () => {
        const image = document.querySelectorAll('img');

        let src = image.attr('src');
           if (src.valueOf() === 'Food') image.src = {food}; 
            
             // Changed src.val() because that didn't work //

    }

componentDidMount() {
     this.images()
)}
```

And this does nothing for me either. Any suggestions?

**MAIN BODY OF CODE:**

(top of code not show)

```
return (
    <GuideDiv>
        <div className='top'>
            <h1>Guides</h1>

            <NewGuide to='/GuideForm'>
                <h2> Add <img src={travel} alt='ravel'/> Guide </h2>
            </NewGuide>
        </div>

        {guided.map(guide =>

        <GuidePost key={guide.id}>
            <div>
                <UserIcon>
                    <img id='guide' alt='type' src={guide.guide_type}/>
                </UserIcon>
                <label className='under'>Guide Type</label>
                <br/>
                    <p>{guide.guide_type}</p>
                <br/>
```

(rest of code not shown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try an mapping. Something like this if its predefined set

```
   import food from '../../images/food.png'
   import car from '../../images/car.png'

    let mapping = {
     FOOD: food,
     CAR: car
    }
    
    const images = () => {
      const image = document.querySelectorAll('img');
      let srcVal = image.attr('src')?.valueOf;
      image.src = mapping[srcVal]; 
      //....rest of your code
    }
```

Check this one and let me know whether it helped you

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU!!!

With a little modification, I did the suggested object map and then:

```
    let imgURL = {
        Food: food,
        Stay: stay,
        Sites: sites,
        Tips: tips
    }
```

`<img id='guide' alt='user' src={imgURL[guide.guide_type]}/>`